# Read a file on HDFS that begins with

Tags: hadoop

Is there a way to read from a sequence file that exists on a certain path on the HDFS, without knowing the full file's name?

For example, if I know that file's name is - modelSomeIterationAOtherIterationB, and it's the only file on that path that begins with "model", is there a way to read it with specifying something like "path/to/file/model*"?

Comment: Yes, the wildcard should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use FileSystem globStatus() method.

//Create FileSystem object fs

fs.globStatus(new Path("path/to/file/model*"))